# CGContextAddArc initial circle angle

Tags: ios, math, cgcontext

Anyways, I have been following this tutorial http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/ in order to make a stop watch using this custom control. (I am not a total beginner, about 4 months in iOS, still new but I understand things.)

However, when I change the CGContextAddArc start angle from 0 to M_PI/2 to look like a clock and initialize the angle to self.angle = 0, it does not start at M_PI/2 but it creates an arc of length M_PI/2. So if you can picture that, imagine the 12 on a clock to the 3 on a clock is the arc length yet I want it to be so when I initialize it to self.angle = 0, it would only show M_PI/2 because that would be the original angle.

Comment: It seems that you forgot high school math ;) `phi = 0` is when the unit vector points all the way to the right. `phi = PI / 2` is when it points upwards, etc.

Comment: Sorry I am still in high school lmao thank you such quick response but can you please expand :D? Fyi I didnt take calculus yet :/

Comment: oh I get what you mean, yes PI/2 is when it points up (1, 0) is the coordinate on the unit circle. Can i make it that self.angle = 0 actually starts on PI/2? so by self.angle = 360, it would come back to PI/2

Comment: FYI it's not calculus, it's trigonometry. [Google "angle 0" and you'll see it...](https://www.google.com/search?q=angle+0&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi) And if you want to "make 0 start at PI / 2", then use addition.

Comment: @JurkoGuba Perhaps rather than asking us to imagine what you mean, you could include screen snapshot and show us precisely what lines of code you changed to what. There are several calls to `CGContextAddArc` that you could be referring to, and I am not following your description of what you wanted or what you got.